# Smooth lines opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

So, I've been trying to make smooth lines with OpenGL for a while without success, and I just noticed that it depends on the window's height:

[image]

And after changing the window's height by 2 px:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, w->width, w->height, 0, 0, 100);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

glColor3f(1, 0, 0);

glBegin(GL_LINES);
glVertex2f(20, 20);
glVertex2f(20 + 200, 20);

glEnd();
```

Does anyone know the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: `glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH)`?  Although it's a long time since I've used the fixed function pipeline.

Comment: I've tried it but it won't work @G.M.

Comment: the syntax you are using is obsolete ... only use OpenGL 3.x and above

Comment: @TazeroutIslam Do you use [Multisample anti-aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multisample_anti-aliasing)?

Comment: Your lines are exactly inbetween the pixel raster,  I guess you have forced some antialiasing via your graphics driver, so the result is as it should be.

Comment: Thanks @derhass for your help , i looked for disabling antialiasing on opengl and i found a solution and it works , i'll post it

Answer (score 2):

```
glDisable(GL_DITHER);
glDisable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
glDisable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
glDisable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);
glHint(GL_POINT_SMOOTH, GL_DONT_CARE);
glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH, GL_DONT_CARE);
glHint(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_DONT_CARE);
#define GL_MULTISAMPLE_ARB 0x809D
glDisable( GL_MULTISAMPLE_ARB) ;
```

this fixed my issue !